# ggplot: color points by fill group without creating a duplicated legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I try to define colors for groups of points, the legend is wrong and duplicated.

My data looks like this:

[image]

My ggplot code to plot multiple groups with error bars is thus:

```
ggplot(datac, aes(x=metric, y=avg, fill=group,color=col)) +
    geom_point(size=5) +
    geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(.9), width=.25, aes(ymin=err_low, ymax=err_high)) +
     theme_minimal()+
     scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent,breaks=c(seq(-1,+1,by=0.05)))
```

which displays
[image]

See how the legend is duplicated and primary legend is shaded with the correct colors. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Try the following: Change your first line to `ggplot(datac, aes(x=metric, y=avg, color=group))`.  Then add `+ scale_color_manual(values=c("View Metric"="blue", "Chat Metric"="green")`.

Comment: Ah thank you. Happy to accept as answer, unless the question was too dumb.